# Windows Compact Framework custom popup notification

Tags: c#, .net, user-interface, notifications, compact-framework

I've been trying to create popup notification for my windows, something like toasts in android.

- It Shouldn't care about active from
- It Should always be on top (for duration it's active)
- It Shouldn't block currently active form
- It Would be nice if its click trough

I know about Microsoft.WindowsCE.Forms.Notification but it doesn't go well with style of application, i tried creating custom class that inherits Notification, but i couldn't find a way to restyle it. I also tried creating topmost form, but that didn't work either, form wouldn't be show at all unless i used ShowDialog, but then it would be autosized to screen size.Here is sample of the way i was planning to create that from:

```
     Form frm = new Form();
     frm.TopMost = true;
     Label lbl = new Label();
     lbl.Text = "TEST";
     lbl.Parent = frm;
     frm.Bounds = new Rectangle(15, 15, 150, 150);
     frm.WindowState = FormWindowState.Normal;
     frm.FormBorderStyle = FormBorderStyle.None;
     frm.AutoScaleMode = AutoScaleMode.None;
     frm.Show();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`Microsoft.WindowsCE.Forms.Notification`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.windowsce.forms.notification(v=vs.100).aspx) is not supported in all platforms. You might want to stick to your own implementation. And about that, here is what I'd do(*not tested*):

Create a Class Library project. Then add a Form. Now add a Label control and a Button control as below:

[image]

Edit Form's properties:

```
ControlBox = false
FormBorderStyle = FixedDialog
TopMost = true
```

Add the following code to form:

```
public partial class FormNotification : Form
{
    private Timer timer;
    public int Duration { get; private set;}

    public FormNotification(string message, int duration)
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        this.labelMessage.Text = message;
        this.Duration = duration;

        this.timer = new Timer();
        this.timer.Interval = 1000;
        this.timer.Tick += new EventHandler(timer_Tick);
    }

    void timer_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (Duration <= 0)
            this.Close();
        this.Duration--;
    }

    private void buttonHide_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        this.Close();
    }

    private void FormNotification_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        this.timer.Enabled = true;
    }
}
```

Now add a class:

**updated**

```
public class CNotification
{
    public CNotification()
    {

    }

    public static void Show(Form owner, string message, int duration)
    {
        FormNotification formNotification = new FormNotification(message, duration);
        formNotification.Owner = owner;
        formNotification.Show();
    }
}
```

Finally use it like:

**updated**

```
// assuming call from a form
CNotification.Show(this, "Hello World", 5);
```

**Ideas for Extending**

- Provide access to Form's controls
- Specify Location & Size
- Add an icon.
- Change opacity of notification

Comment: This worked, but there are few problems, even if its marked as stay on top it goes behind currently focused form when it looses focus, also all of forms are maximized, when notification appears top bar(with battery, wifi signal, etc.) appears which it shouldn't (can't use maximize since it isn't click through.

Comment: You are right, I have added something to keep it on top, see my updated answer. For top bar, depending on platform, you can  hide this bar: A simple google search will reveal answer.

Comment: yeah, i managed to fix that by overriding focused and making it return false every time:
'public override bool Focused
        {
            get
            {
                return false;
            }
        }'
Anyways i managed to do what i wanted thanks to your help.